# Easiest way to strip newline character from input string in pasteboard

Tags: macos, unix, shell

Hopefully fairly straightforward, to explain the use case when I run the following command (OS X 10.6):

```
$ pwd | pbcopy
```

the pasteboard contains a newline character at the end. I'd like to get rid of it.

Comment: Sidenote: if the reason you want to do this is to paste into the "Go to" field in Finder (type `~`), you can just use `pwd | pbcopy`, paste in the text field and then press backspace.

Answer (score 153, accepted):

`pwd | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy`

Comment: This also makes for a nice alias, `alias copy="tr -d '\n' | pbcopy"`.

Comment: Wouldn't that strip all new lines? What if I only want the last newline removed?

Comment: @davidmh - Yea that strip all of them. I just always remove the last  character which works has been working well for me: `head -c -1` .  http://taylor.woodstitch.com/linux/copy-local-clipboard-remote-ssh-server/

Comment: In bashrc, I like: `alias cpwd="pwd | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy"` :)

Comment: Even though the 'head -c -1' from @TaylorHawkes doesn't work for me on OSX (BSD head doesn't like negative values), it does point out that it strips newlines from all lines, not just the trailing one.  A variant that does work is `alias pbc='xargs echo -n | pbcopy'`

Comment: If you install the coreutils on OSX you can use `ghead -c -1`

Answer (score 46):

```
printf $(pwd) | pbcopy
```

or

```
echo -n $(pwd) | pbcopy
```

Note that these should really be quoted in case there are whitespace characters in the directory name. For example:

```
echo -n "$(pwd)" | pbcopy
```

Comment: First one is unsafe: there could be %'s in the string.

Comment: You can make it safe like this: `printf '%s' $(pwd) | pbcopy`

Comment: The second command is very valuable. It is great to know about the "echo without newline" option: `echo -n "text "` or `"text \c"`

Comment: This solution worked better for me because I'm using an alias to copy last command : alias cplc='echo -n $(fc -ln -1)  | pbcopy'

Answer (score 12):

I wrote a utility called `noeol` to solve this problem. It pipes stdin to stdout, but leaves out the trailing newline if there is one. E.g.

```
pwd | noeol | pbcopy
```

…I aliased `copy` to `noeol | pbcopy`.

Check it out here: https://github.com/Sidnicious/noeol

Answer (score 3):

For me I was having issues with the `tr -d '\n'` approach. On OSX I happened to have the coreutils package installed via `brew install coreutils`. This provides all the "normal" GNU utilities prefixed with a <kbd>g</kbd> in front of their typical names. So `head` would be `ghead` for example.

Using this worked more safely IMO:

```
pwd | ghead -c -1 | pbcopy
```

You can use `od` to see what's happening with the output:

```
$ pwd | ghead -c -1 | /usr/bin/od -h
0000000      552f    6573    7372    732f    696d    676e    6c6f    6c65
0000020      696c
0000022
```

vs.

```
$ pwd | /usr/bin/od -h
0000000      552f    6573    7372    732f    696d    676e    6c6f    6c65
0000020      696c    000a
0000023
```

The difference?

The `00` and `0a` are the hexcodes for a nul and newline. The `ghead -c -1` merely "chomps" the last character from the output before handing it off to `| pbcopy`.

```
$ man ascii | grep -E '\b00\b|\b0a\b'
     00 nul   01 soh   02 stx   03 etx   04 eot   05 enq   06 ack   07 bel
     08 bs    09 ht    0a nl    0b vt    0c np    0d cr    0e so    0f si
```

Answer (score 0):

We can first delete the trailing newline if any, and then give it to `pbcopy` as [follows](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/140738):

```bash
your_command | perl -0 -pe 's/\n\Z//' | pbcopy
```

We can also create an alias of this:

```bash
alias pbc="perl -0 -pe 's/\n\Z//' | pbcopy"
```

Then the command would become:

```bash
pwd | pbc
```